# Complicated curve fitting using piece-wise functions

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, astronomy, scipy-optimize

This is my first ever post so please let me know if I miss out crucial information. I am trying to perform curve fitting of two parameters. Basically we are given `z_array` (redshift) `m_B_eff` (magnitude) The curve fitting needs to output fitted values of `OmegaM` and `OmegaA`.

The arrays are as follows:

```
z_array = [
    0.458, 0.354, 0.425, 0.374, 0.42, 0.372, 0.378, 0.453, 0.465, 0.498,
    0.655, 0.4, 0.615, 0.48, 0.45, 0.388, 0.57, 0.49, 0.495, 0.656, 0.828,
    0.45, 0.43, 0.58, 0.763, 0.526, 0.172, 0.619, 0.592, 0.55, 0.18, 0.374,
    0.472, 0.43, 0.657, 0.612, 0.32, 0.579, 0.45, 0.581, 0.416, 0.83, 0.03, 
    0.05, 0.026, 0.075, 0.026, 0.014, 0.101, 0.02, 0.036, 0.045, 0.043,
    0.018, 0.079, 0.088, 0.063, 0.071, 0.052, 0.05
]

m_B_eff = [
    23.11, 22.38, 22.13, 21.72, 22.55, 22.26, 22.58, 23.17, 23.33,
    23.71, 23.27, 22.36, 23.19, 22.96, 22.51, 22.65, 23.27, 23.1,
    22.83, 23.57, 24.65, 23.17, 23.13, 23.46, 24.47, 23.15, 20.17,
    23.8, 24.42, 23.51, 20.43, 23.52, 23.11, 22.57, 23.83, 23.69,
    21.86, 23.48, 22.83, 23.09, 22.57, 24.32, 16.26, 17.63, 16.08,
    18.43, 16.28, 14.47, 19.16, 15.18, 16.66, 17.61, 17.19, 15.61,
    18.27, 19.28, 18.24, 18.33, 17.54, 17.69
]
```

In what feels to be a poor attempt, I have attempted to feed in values of the `z_array` into the function to get `scipy` to calculate the best fit parameters for `OmegaA` and `OmegaM`, despite this, the outputs of both are on the order of 10^16... they should be on the order of unity. Printing the values as `scipy` tries to fit them reveals that both omega values just explode in size

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func2(x, OmegaA, OmegaM):

    resultArr = []
    LfuncArr = []
    K = 0
    for r in range(len(x)):

        if OmegaM + OmegaA == 1:
            K = 1
            LfuncArr.append(np.sqrt(np.abs(K))*(integrate.quad(lambda y: (((1+y)**2)*(1+y*OmegaM)-(2+y)*OmegaA*y)**-0.5, 0, x[r],limit=10000)[0]))
        elif  OmegaM + OmegaA > 1: 
            K = 1-OmegaM-OmegaA
            LfuncArr.append(np.sin(np.sqrt(np.abs(K))*(integrate.quad(lambda y: (((1+y)**2)*(1+y*OmegaM)-(2+y)*OmegaA*y)**-0.5, 0, x[r],limit=10000)[0])))
        elif OmegaM + OmegaA < 1:
            K = 1-OmegaM-OmegaA
            LfuncArr.append(np.sinh(np.sqrt(np.abs(K))*(integrate.quad(lambda y: (((1+y)**2)*(1+y*OmegaM)-(2+y)*OmegaA*y)**-0.5, 0, x[r],limit=10000)[0])))


        resultArr.append((5*np.log10(c*(1+x[r])/np.sqrt(np.abs(K)) * LfuncArr[r]) + 17.931))


    return resultArr

plt.plot

p0 = 0.5, 0.5
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(func2, z_array, m_B_eff, p0, maxfev=50000)
```

Expected output fit values of the cosmological parameters: `OmegaA` and `OmegaM` to be on the order of unity.
`K` and `Lfunc` will be defined according to the piece-wise function

For further information about the function I am trying to plot it can be found here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/304265/pdf page 566.

Comment: while I love the cosmology part is seems much irrelevant to a question of how to feed data into scipy curve_fit function. I would suggest you re-edit the question and reduce it to a minimal example that shows the problem you are having. curve_fit example is in the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html.  If you would care to provide values of ```z_array, m_B_eff``` we could probably help you more with your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I have added the values of the arrays above and will make some changes to the wording, I was trying to keep provide a little context so it would be clear which parameters I am trying to fit. :)

Comment: We cannot know if this fit function is defined correctly beyond obvious coding issues. That surely depends on the theory of the underlying physics.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity, that is what I was indeed asking, whether the function itself would actually adhere to the piecewise part or not, such as is it compatible with scipy.curve_fit or does it get confused at the definition, I currently get an error stating: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" Which seems to be an issue with Lfunc.

Comment: Thank you for providing context. According to the docs for quad at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html the function return, upper limit, and lower limit must all be individual scalar values. In your current code, at least one of these is an array. You would need to re-write you code so that these are all scalar values for each call to quad.

Comment: I found it curious that the standard vapor pressure equation, "y = exp(a + (b/x) + c*log(x))", gave a good fit to the data as a smooth approximating equation with parameters a = 3.2204420280465569E+00, b = -8.7429270070915935E-04, and c = 1.1202478966252780E-01 yielding RMSE = 0.316 and R-squared = 0.987. It seemed strange to me that the equation for vapor pressure fits the data well, and though this might coincidence I thought it worth noting.

Comment: Currently a lot better than my fit haha! I believe I have sorted out the integration calculation buy my output of omega values just explodes as it runs through, finally resting on 1e16, a mere 16 orders of magnitude out, I know astronomers like "order of magnitude estimates" but I may struggle to excuse this one.

Comment: so `c` is speed of light? What about the division by `H_0`?

Comment: You could make it a bit more readable by actually defining the integral kernel as a function and use `quad`s `args=()` argument to pass the omegas.